# What is the "shape" of the electric potential of a moving charge? Can the field be derived as its gradient?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, potential, vector-fields, visualization

This is motivated by Electricity and Magnetism, 3rd Ed., by Purcell and Morin, Section 5.6.

Below is my derivation of the Lorentz transformation of the electric field due to a moving charge whose rest frame is represented by unbarred components.  The charge $Q$ moves at speed $\beta$ in the direction indicated by ${\parallel }$ subscripted coordinates.  It coincides with the 3-space origin of the barred system at $t=0.$

As pointed out in the book, the field is parallel to the radial direction from the origin where the moving source charge is instantaneously located, but changes strength with the angle of the radial position vector of the test particle.

In the case of a static potential the field is simply the 3-space gradient of the potential, and for a point charge the potential and electric field are both spherically symmetric.  The gradient points in a direction normal to equipotential surfaces.

On a plane lying parallel to the direction of motion at rest in the unbarred system (charge rest frame), we draw concentric circles around the charge, representing equipotential surfaces.  From the barred system, those circle will be foreshortened in the direction of travel.  Thus the field vectors will no longer be normal to the equipotential surfaces except at $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}.$

On one hand, the fact that the electric field is directed radial from the instantaneous location of the moving source charge seems intuitively obvious.  Lorentz contraction is an affine transformation of 3-space preserving lines and points of intersection.

On the other hand, the electric field no longer appears to be parallel to the gradient of the potential, except in the special cases already addressed.

**Is there a way of explaining this apparent contradiction?  Can a useful visual representation of a moving source charge's potential be produced?**

#### First do the transformation algebra.

[image]

#### Plug the results into the Coulomb's law expression.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations!  You have discovered an important fact about dynamic electromagnetic fields.  For dynamic fields, the electric field is no longer simply given by the gradient of the potential $V$, but is instead given by
$$
\vec{E} = - \vec{\nabla} V - \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}
$$
where $\vec{A}$ is the vector potential (i.e., the field for which $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{A} = \vec{B}$.)  In general, the equation $\vec{E} = - \vec{\nabla} V$ is only true for static (or approximately static) fields.

For further details on this, you'll need to look at higher-level texts than Purcell & Morin.  The standard undergraduate text for such material, at least here in the USA, is *Introduction to Electrodynamics* by Griffiths.  IIRC, this material is discussed in Chapter 10, though you'll need a full understanding of Maxwell's equations (Chapter 7) before you delve into that.

Comment: I'm familiar with the vector potential, and Purcell and Morin do introduce it. https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_14.html  https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_15.html  I don't find it very picturesque. To some extent, it begs the question I'm trying to get at.  That is, how does magnetism arise from moving electric fields.  Purcell and Morin seem to do a nice job treating things in a way that is interesting to me, and its easy reading.